# WordPress and Subversion on Mac

Tags: wordpress, svn, repository, development-environment

#### Few things you need to know

*- I'm not a native English speaker

 - I'm new to Stack Overflow

 - I'm new to Subversion*

#### What I'm trying to do

I'm developing *WordPress* themes & plugins and never thought of using *Subversion* until a few days ago. I've downloaded *Versions* and read all the documentation on their website. I'm trying to use it for plugin development, but I don't understand how.

I know how to *create a repo*, *import*, *checkout*, *commit*. I just don't know how to use all this for plugin development (or themes, or anything).

> So I got *MAMP*, a few sites in my htdocs folder (WordPress mostly)
>   and *Versions*. Let's say I want to work on a plugin, on
>   **website_one**, what exactly should I do? How does this all work?

#### What I've tried

I tried creating a *repository* on my desktop, *importing* the whole **wordpress_one** site, *checking out* a working copy of it, modifying things and all but how do I work with that? How do I preview my changes?

Should I only import and checkout the plugin files? How do I see what I'm doing? I don't know if you understand what I'm asking for. I feel lost, I feel like I don't understand *Subversion*.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: If you needed a quick guide, here's a step-by-step one: https://wpza.net/wordpress-setup/uploading-wordpress-plugins-to-an-svn-using-a-mac/

Comment: Thank you very much! It's been a few years already, I figured it out and everything's fine now! But thanks!

Comment: Good to know! It's for anyone else looking to solve this too. Due to people wanting to make plugins for Gutenberg recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read the article by Tom McFarlin explains this very well: https://tommcfarlin.com/subversion-for-wordpress-development/

I did a French adaptation here: http://additifstabac.free.fr/index.php/organiser-installation-wordpress-developper-plugin-subversion-svn/